# How to close a Colorbox from a Controller in CodeIgniter?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, colorbox

I have a Colorbox (lightbox) loading a specific controller/view. Is there any way for me to close the colorbox from within the controller?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ostensibly you could echo out the `hideLightbox()` method from your controller:

```
echo '<script>hideLightbox(); return false;</script>';
```

but I'm not sure this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use this :

```
<?= "$(document).ready(function() { $.colorbox.close(); });"; ?>
```

(Insert this the bottom of your view)

But you may be use a specific ajax call and I think you should perhaps to see to optimize this (without change your controller code).

Good Luck ! ;)